# printing token and line causing the parsing error

Tags: parsing, bison

is there a way to know where did the error happened in the parser ,it means which **token** did that error and which **line**, I don't know how to use yylineno which can be easily used in the lex file ? 
thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Have you checked the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Locations.html#Locations)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enable debug traces in both flex (`%option debug` and set `yy_flex_debug` to 1) and the parser (`%debug` and set `yydebug` to 1).  See their documentations.

Comment: I need to print them on the screen not for debugging, I am building a parser so when it happen I need to print the token caused that and at which line did that happen

Comment: So you are actually looking for `%location` and `%error-verbose` in Bison's documentation.